# How to capture error message and How to concatenate the data of the error records into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, concatenation, error-messaging

I have a code as part of a project. The code validates the below conditions.

- Check if item no is null
- Check if length of item number is equal to 5 characters
- Check if item description is null
- Check if length of item description is less than 240 characters.

the code will validate all the above conditions for each and every record of a table. If any of the above validation fails for any record, Then the status of that particular record will change to 'V' and the error message will be printed, where the error message will display at which condition of the above mentioned validation is failed.

For ex: For a particular record, if item no is null then the status of the particular record will be updated to 'V' and the error message will be printed as 'Item No is null so the status is updated to V'.

Now I have the below scenario to work upon

1. Create a table error_log with sequence_no, error_message and error_data.
2. Error message will have the actual error message and error data will have concatenated value of all the data.
3. When there is an error, the error message should be captured in error_log table in error_message column and error_data should have concatenated value of all the columns i,e. error_data should have concatenated data of the columns of a record for which the validation has failed.

Can you please help me how to capture the error message in error_log table and the how to concatenate the error record columns data in error_data column of error_message table

Comment: Can anyone please help in providing the solution to achieve the above scenario

Comment: _"Can anyone please help in providing the solution to achieve the above scenario"_  Patience, Grasshopper.  You posted this plea a mere one hour after posting the original question.  This is a global forum. The person with the information you seek may very will live 12 time zones away from you and was going to bed just as you posted.  All participants area volunteers.

Comment: @NaveenRagam . . . Why would you allow bad data into the table to begin with?  All those conditions can easily be ensured using `check` constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you describe would be best handled by proper table design and the use of constraints, which would enforce these conditions at all times. Define column lengths to meet your requirements (5 characters, 240 characters) or with NOT NULL constraints, and you'll never *need* a procedure like that. If that isn't possible, then consider that a simple `INSERT as SELECT` command could do you what you're describing:

```
insert into error_table 
       (error_date, error_pk, error_message) 
       select sysdate, [data_table.primary_key], 'field A is too long' 
         from data_table where length(field_a) > 5;
```

You would need one insert statement for each condition you were checking. Also, I would only store the primary key of each data row, not a duplicate copy of all of the data, unless you needed to track all of the changes to the data over time.